# How to get total adCost and adClicks data for a property in GA4 Data API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

In the previous Universal Analytics API, I would get the total ad cost and total ad clicks for a single day on a single view by making an API request that includes those metrics but no dimensions. However, with the new GA4 Data API, I can't make this same request with the advertiserAdCost and advertiserAdClicks metrics as I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The dimensions and metrics are incompatible.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the total ad cost and total ad clicks for a single property with this new API?

---

Using [GA's API explorer for the new GA4 Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) I tried running the following request:

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "advertiserAdCost"
    },
    {
      "name": "advertiserAdClicks"
    },
    {
      "name": "advertiserAdCostPerClick"
    }
  ],
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "2023-01-11",
      "endDate": "2023-01-12"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expected to receive a response with a report indicating the total ad cost, ad clicks, and ad cost per click for that single day across my property. Instead I received this error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The dimensions and metrics are incompatible.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some dimensions and metrics are incompatible.   This is most often due to the fact that the data need to create the report across these dimensions and metrics simple dosent exist.

The only way to fix it would be to remove one of the dimensions or metrics that is incompatible

Answer (score 0):

try to add a dimension like `sessionCampaignName`
you can test it in [this link](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/), with out the dimension it recommend to add the dimension

[image]

Adding the dimension `sessionCampaignName`  it returns the result, however in my case is empty because I have no data.
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get ad click / cost without the sessionCampaignName demension? The problem is that it also returns organic/referal and direct metrics and also splits the data for each seperate ad. instead of just the clicks/cost of all my ads combined.